# Are there any modification of BNF with parameters

Tags: parsing, computer-science, bnf, ebnf

I mean something like

```
LISTOF(EL) := "[" EL ("," EL)* "]"
LISTNUM := LISTOF(NUMBER)
LISTID := LISTOF(IDENT)
```

so, with definitions

```
NUMBER := ('0'-'9')*
IDENT := ('a'-'z'|'A'-'Z')*
```

we have following

`[435,657,44]` is example of `LISTNUM`,

`[dsf,thg,ewre]` is example of `LISTID`.

Or another example (e means empty string)

```
A(0) := e 
A(n) := "a" A(n-1) | e
```

so, A(5) is set of all strings consist of 'a' with length not more than 5

Are there any science works describing something similar to this? Can we describe our grammars in such way and still be able to parse it in acceptable time?

Comment: Of course you *can* do this.  One simple way is to treat your parameterized BNF rules as macros and simply expand them to conventional BNF.  The question is *should* you do this?  Does the additional expressiveness buy you anything in practice?  I've built a lot of grammars; I don't think so. YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commonly used meta syntaxes such as Bnf, Abnf and Ebnf doesn't have parameterized rules. However Iso Ebnf is extensible as per the standard. If I remember correctly, the standard actually shows an example of introducing parameters.

You can get the standard [here](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/s026153_ISO_IEC_14977_1996(E).zip) for free.